# Implementing shorted path Algorithm in autodesk forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I am trying to draw a geometry on my viewer based on shortest path between 2 object.
till now I know how we can draw custom geometry using vector3.
also I have figured out which algorithm I can use to find the shortest path between point A to Point B.
here are few :
Dijkstra's
A* Search
I have seen this example where this algorithm is been implemented and I am trying similar solution in forge viewer here is the [Link](https://dhruvmisra.github.io/Pathfinding-Visualizer-ThreeJS/)

also if someone can help me how can I restrict first person view to through walls like in the above sample. right now in forge viewer I can penetrate through wall which I want to avoid or is there any way that I can Identify the walls

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the viewer does not provide a lot of support for path-finding, so most of it you would have to do manually.

Here's some of the functionality that *is* available that might be handy in your case:

- you can "shoot rays" inside the scene and compute their intersections with the nearest geometry, for example, using `viewer.impl.rayIntersect(ray, ignoreTransparent)`

  - for example, this could be used to detect collisions with walls if you had some kind of an avatar inside the scene
- if needed, you can retrieve the geometry of individual objects in the scene using the "fragment list":

```js
let frags = viewer.model.getFragmentList();
let tree = viewer.model.getInstanceTree();
tree.enumNodeFragments(dbid, function (fragid) {
    let mesh = frags.getVizmesh(fragid);
    // Do something with the mesh...
});
```

Comment: Thanks Petr this added more knowledge to me and trying to get this working with your above solution